# Bind Parameters with Tableset values in Datamodel in Oracle Fusion

Tags: sql, datamodel, bi-publisher, oracle-fusion-apps

For PO Queries , I want to get the `segment1` column  from `po_headers_all` table values based on selection of the Business Unit Name column from `hr_operating_units` tables

I have tried but not getting the `segment1` values based on Businesss unit selection

[image: image of LOVS]

Comment: Maybe your parameter is misspelled somewhere? Should that be requisition?

Comment: no thats not the issue , are the sql queries right?@EdHayes3